# Setting up Laravel's OAuth 2.0 is Dingo API

Tags: laravel, api, laravel-5, oauth-2.0, dingo-api

I use Laravel 5.3 with Dingo API, and I'm trying to get Laravel's OAuth 2.0 (aka Passport) to work with Dingo's Authentication.

I added the OAuth 2.0 provider in `config/api.php`, which I found [here](https://github.com/dingo/api/issues/219):

```
'auth' => [
    'oauth' => function($app) {
        $provider = new Dingo\Api\Auth\LeagueOAuth2Provider($app['oauth2.resource-server']);

        $provider->setUserCallback(function($id) {
            return User::find($id);
        });

        $provider->setClientCallback(function($id) {
            return Client::find($id);
        });
        return $provider;
    }
]
```

And then I added the `api.auth` middleware onto my route:

```
$api = app('Dingo\Api\Routing\Router');

$api->version('v2', function($api) {
    # ...
    $api->get('test', ['middleware' => 'api.auth', 'App\Http\Controllers\v2\SnippetController@test']);
});
```

And when request the `/api/test`, I get a `500` HTTP response with this error:

```
Call to undefined method Closure::authenticate()
```

The full JSON response (which includes the trace) can be found [here](https://pybin.pw/WIobIQNB)

Sadly [the docs](https://github.com/dingo/api/wiki/Authentication#oauth-20) barely mention setting up Dingo with `league/oauth2-server`, which is what Laravel uses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to create a new provider on `app/Providers/PassportDingoProvider.php` with the following code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;
use Dingo\Api\Routing\Route;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager;
use Dingo\Api\Auth\Provider\Authorization;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\UnauthorizedHttpException;

class PassportDingoProvider extends Authorization
{
    /**
     * Illuminate authentication manager.
     *
     * @var \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard
     */
    protected $auth;

    /**
     * The guard driver name.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $guard = 'api';

    /**
     * Create a new basic provider instance.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager $auth
     */
    public function __construct(AuthManager $auth)
    {
        $this->auth = $auth->guard($this->guard);
    }

    /**
     * Authenticate request with a Illuminate Guard.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param \Dingo\Api\Routing\Route $route
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function authenticate(Request $request, Route $route)
    {
        if (! $user = $this->auth->user()) {
            throw new UnauthorizedHttpException(
                get_class($this),
                'Invalid API token'
            );
        }

        return $user;
    }

    /**
     * Get the providers authorization method.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAuthorizationMethod()
    {
        return 'Bearer';
    }
}
```

And then I added this in `config/api.php`:

```
'auth' => [
    'custom' => \App\Providers\PassportDingoProvider::class
]
```

Later on, I was able to use the `api.auth` Middleware to authenticate my routes.

You can also get the user via `Auth::guard('api')->user()` instead of `Auth::user()`

Answer (score -2):

According to docs, you should check and change your config to this:

```
'jwt' => 'Dingo\Api\Auth\Provider\JWT'
```

See the issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/dingo/api/issues/611)

Hope this helps!

Comment: So I would be using JWT instead of OAuth 2.0 in that case?

Comment: But I still want to authenticate via OAuth 2.0 as well, that config would disable OAuth 2.0 wouldn't it